# Load user uploaded images into video (probably swf)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

To give you some background, I'm researching an upcoming project which needs to have very similar functionality to the elf yourself website. How would you go about this? My top-level understanding is that we would need to create an animation in Adobe Animate and export it as an swf with some actionscript that loads the user uploaded image into the swf. Would I need something like this to regenerate the swf: https://github.com/claus/as3swf ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

App #1. You are to create an animation, where the head is a place-holder. The app must obtain the replacement photo in the preloading phase via the photo id (see below), then all the head does is replaces its content with the replacement photo in its class constructor.

App #2. The other part of the app is the admin app, which allows the user to select the photo, to crop it (probably in a circle area), resize it to the optimal width/height and upload the result to your server so that photo is available to the App #1.

App #3. Server, that handles the uploaded photos and allows to access App #1 with a parameter which tells the id of photo to preload and show.